# EditText Widget not Showing up in Form Widgets

Tags: android, forms, widget, android-edittext

Would I need to do an SDK update or something to get the EditText widget added to the list of available Form Widgets under the Palette of the Graphical Layout?  It's not showing up there.  I picked the highest API - 17, still with no luck.  Thanks.

Comment: Would the EditText widget be the same thing as a TextView widget with its 'editable' property set to 'true', even though that property is marked as 'deprecated'???

Answer (score 0):

I have EditTexts of different kind (plain, Person name, password, mail, phone, date, etc.) in Text Fields group of the Palette. It's below Form Widgets. (I work in Eclipse.) Here's the [Palette](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/FAYm1NL3adInDqxG-.png):

Comment: I see what you're saying - that those widgets are under the Text Fields category, not the Form Widgets, as described by my textbook.  Regardless, I just copied/pasted the XML document from the textbook, which has the code for everything.  Thanks very much sir!!!